# При обращении к index.php -> cp1251, к shop.php -> utf-8 {.htaccess}

Tags: .htaccess

В общем у меня следующая проблема есть файл index.php который написан очень криво, и переписывать уже нет времени... в нем используется кодировка windows-1251

И есть shop.php (CodeIgniter) в котором кодировка utf-8

Вопрос: Можно ли задать в .htaccess что-бы при обращении была разная кодировка?

Вопрос2: Как это сделать?)

Comment: А что мешает файл перекодировать?

Comment: Объем файлов. Криво-рукость первоначального когда.

Comment: Гениальное решение) вот только применил к своему коду) Даешь конвертацию в ответ =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

а) Не вижу связи между кодировкой файла и кодом.

б) Пропишите в `index.php` :

`<?php
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=cp1251');`

И не морочьте людям голову.

Answer (score 0):

Открыть стандартным(виндовым) блокнотом файл index.php, клацнуть сохранить как и выбрать кодировку utf-8. И не морочить интернеты с разными кодировками одного сайта.